# Nav Menu meta failing to import

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I'm the author of the Nav Menu Roles plugin that lets you display/hide menu items based on the user's role.  It has come to my attention that the menu item meta does not import when using the regular WordPress plugin/tool for importing.

Each menu item is essentially just a post in the database, and I've been saving the data as post meta.  It appears in the exported XML.  Here's a sample from a test export I just did locally.

```
<item>
    <title>Art &amp; Design</title>
    <link>http://localhost/blog/2013/01/13/263/</link>
    <pubDate>Mon, 14 Jan 2013 03:36:16 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>helga</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/blog/2013/01/13/263/</guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>263</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date>2013-01-13 22:36:16</wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt>2013-01-14 03:36:16</wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name>263</wp:post_name>
    <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>1</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type>nav_menu_item</wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <category domain="nav_menu" nicename="main-menu"><![CDATA[Main Menu]]></category>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_type</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[taxonomy]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_menu_item_parent</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_object_id</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[6]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_object</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[category]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_target</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_classes</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:1:{i:0;s:6:"design";}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_xfn</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_url</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_nav_menu_role</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:2:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";i:1;s:12:"shop_manager";}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
```

But then on import, the meta key `_nav_menu_role` doesn't even appear in the database.  I'm running a multisite locally, but the user who brought this issue to my attention is not.  I'd like to fix this issue for everyone who uses this plugin, but I am so stumped about where to even begin looking.  I thought it might be a problem with serialization/non-serialization, but the key isn't corrupt, it isn't even there after the import.

**UPDATE**: I've investigated the importer plugin and for menu items, the plugin only imports the traditional, pre-defined meta.. such as 'class'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ultimately with the WordPress Importer plugin.  I could hack at it (and have suggested an improvement to the developers) but I am going to got around this by writing a custom Importer of my own.  It isn't the most convenient (to re-upload the .XML file) but in cases where users have complex menus it is better than losing the meta values.

It needs more testing, but I should be adding it to my plugin in the next version.

**Custom Importer for Menu Item Meta**

The problem was ultimately with the WordPress Importer plugin.  I could hack at it (and have suggested an improvement to the developers) but I am going to got around this by writing a custom Importer of my own.  It isn't the most convenient (to re-upload the .XML file) but in cases where users have complex menus it is better than losing the meta values.

It needs more testing, but I should be adding it to my plugin in the next version.

**Custom Importer for Menu Item Meta**

```
<?php
/**
 * Nav Menu Roles Importer - import menu item meta
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if ( class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {
    class Nav_Menu_Roles_Import extends WP_Importer {

    var $max_wxr_version = 1.2; // max. supported WXR version

    var $id; // WXR attachment ID

    // information to import from WXR file
    var $version;
    var $posts = array();
    var $base_url = '';


        /**
         * __construct function.
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->import_page = 'nav_menu_roles';
        }

    /**
     * Registered callback function for the WordPress Importer
     *
     * Manages the three separate stages of the WXR import process
     */
    function dispatch() {
        $this->header();

        $step = empty( $_GET['step'] ) ? 0 : (int) $_GET['step'];
        switch ( $step ) {
            case 0:
                $this->greet();
                break;
            case 1:
                check_admin_referer( 'import-upload' );
                if ( $this->handle_upload() ) {
                    $file = get_attached_file( $this->id );
                    set_time_limit(0);
                    $this->import( $file );
                }
                break;
        }

        $this->footer();
    }

    /**
     * The main controller for the actual import stage.
     *
     * @param string $file Path to the WXR file for importing
     */
    function import( $file ) {
        add_filter( 'import_post_meta_key', array( $this, 'is_valid_meta_key' ) );
        add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', array( &$this, 'bump_request_timeout' ) );

        $this->import_start( $file );

        wp_suspend_cache_invalidation( true );
        $this->process_nav_menu_meta();
        wp_suspend_cache_invalidation( false );

        $this->import_end();
    }

    /**
     * Parses the WXR file and prepares us for the task of processing parsed data
     *
     * @param string $file Path to the WXR file for importing
     */
    function import_start( $file ) {
        if ( ! is_file($file) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Sorry, there has been an error.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</strong><br />';
            echo __( 'The file does not exist, please try again.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</p>';
            $this->footer();
            die();
        }

        $import_data = $this->parse( $file );

        if ( is_wp_error( $import_data ) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Sorry, there has been an error.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</strong><br />';
            echo esc_html( $import_data->get_error_message() ) . '</p>';
            $this->footer();
            die();
        }

        $this->version = $import_data['version'];
        $this->posts = $import_data['posts'];
        $this->base_url = esc_url( $import_data['base_url'] );

        wp_defer_term_counting( true );
        wp_defer_comment_counting( true );

        do_action( 'import_start' );
    }

    /**
     * Performs post-import cleanup of files and the cache
     */
    function import_end() {
        wp_import_cleanup( $this->id );

        wp_cache_flush();
        foreach ( get_taxonomies() as $tax ) {
            delete_option( "{$tax}_children" );
            _get_term_hierarchy( $tax );
        }

        wp_defer_term_counting( false );
        wp_defer_comment_counting( false );

        echo '<p>' . __( 'All done.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . ' <a href="' . admin_url() . '">' . __( 'Have fun!', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</a>' . '</p>';

        do_action( 'import_end' );
    }

    /**
     * Handles the WXR upload and initial parsing of the file to prepare for
     * displaying author import options
     *
     * @return bool False if error uploading or invalid file, true otherwise
     */
    function handle_upload() {
        $file = wp_import_handle_upload();

        if ( isset( $file['error'] ) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Sorry, there has been an error.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</strong><br />';
            echo esc_html( $file['error'] ) . '</p>';
            return false;
        } else if ( ! file_exists( $file['file'] ) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Sorry, there has been an error.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</strong><br />';
            printf( __( 'The export file could not be found at <code>%s</code>. It is likely that this was caused by a permissions problem.', 'nav-menu-roles' ), esc_html( $file['file'] ) );
            echo '</p>';
            return false;
        }

        $this->id = (int) $file['id'];
        $import_data = $this->parse( $file['file'] );
        if ( is_wp_error( $import_data ) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Sorry, there has been an error.', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</strong><br />';
            echo esc_html( $import_data->get_error_message() ) . '</p>';
            return false;
        }

        $this->version = $import_data['version'];
        if ( $this->version > $this->max_wxr_version ) {
            echo '<div class="error"><p><strong>';
            printf( __( 'This WXR file (version %s) may not be supported by this version of the importer. Please consider updating.', 'nav-menu-roles' ), esc_html($import_data['version']) );
            echo '</strong></p></div>';
        }

        return true;
    }



    /**
     * Create new posts based on import information
     *
     * Posts marked as having a parent which doesn't exist will become top level items.
     * Doesn't create a new post if: the post type doesn't exist, the given post ID
     * is already noted as imported or a post with the same title and date already exists.
     * Note that new/updated terms, comments and meta are imported for the last of the above.
     */
    function process_nav_menu_meta() {
        foreach ( $this->posts as $post ) {

            // we only want to deal with the nav_menu_item posts
            if ( 'nav_menu_item' != $post['post_type'] || ! empty( $post['post_id'] ) )
                continue;

            // ok we've got a nav_menu_item
            $post_id = (int) $post['post_id'];

            // add/update post meta
            if ( isset( $post['postmeta'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $post['postmeta'] as $meta ) {
                    $key = apply_filters( 'import_post_meta_key', $meta['key'] );
                    $value = false;


                    if ( $key ) {
                        // export gets meta straight from the DB so could have a serialized string
                        if ( ! $value )
                            $value = maybe_unserialize( $meta['value'] );

                        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
                        do_action( 'import_post_meta', $post_id, $key, $value );

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        unset( $this->posts );
    }




    /**
     * Parse a WXR file
     *
     * @param string $file Path to WXR file for parsing
     * @return array Information gathered from the WXR file
     */
    function parse( $file ) {
        $parser = new WXR_Parser();
        return $parser->parse( $file );
    }

    // Display import page title
    function header() {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        screen_icon();
        echo '<h2>' . __( 'Import Nav Menu Roles', 'nav-menu-roles' ) . '</h2>';

        $updates = get_plugin_updates();
        $basename = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
        if ( isset( $updates[$basename] ) ) {
            $update = $updates[$basename];
            echo '<div class="error"><p><strong>';
            printf( __( 'A new version of this importer is available. Please update to version %s to ensure compatibility with newer export files.', 'nav-menu-roles' ), $update->update->new_version );
            echo '</strong></p></div>';
        }
    }

    // Close div.wrap
    function footer() {
        echo '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Display introductory text and file upload form
     */
    function greet() {
        echo '<div class="narrow">';
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Re-Upload your normal WordPress eXtended RSS (WXR) file and we&#8217;ll import the Nav Menu Roles and any other missing post meta for the Nav Menu items.', 'nav-menu-roles' ).'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Choose a WXR (.xml) file to upload, then click Upload file and import.', 'nav-menu-roles' ).'</p>';
        wp_import_upload_form( 'admin.php?import=nav_menu_roles&amp;step=1' );
        echo '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Decide if the given meta key maps to information we will want to import
     *
     * @param string $key The meta key to check
     * @return string|bool The key if we do want to import, false if not
     */
    function is_valid_meta_key( $key ) {
        // skip attachment metadata since we'll regenerate it from scratch
        // skip _edit_lock as not relevant for import
        if ( in_array( $key, array( '_wp_attached_file', '_wp_attachment_metadata', '_edit_lock' ) ) )
            return false;
        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Added to http_request_timeout filter to force timeout at 60 seconds during import
     * @return int 60
     */
    function bump_request_timeout() {
        return 60;
    }

    // return the difference in length between two strings
    function cmpr_strlen( $a, $b ) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    }


    } // end class
} // end if
```

Comment: As of version 1.3 an importer is included in the plugin.